# Where to find QGIS geoprocessing results?

Tags: qgis, raster, geoprocessing, raster-calculator

Is there a way to access in QGIS 2.6.1 something like the Geoprocessing Results window found in ArcGIS?

The History and Log window in QGIS appears to show the geoprocessing results from SAGA, OTB and other algorithms but nothing from the Raster Calculator, which is what I am really after. There does not appear to be anything useful in the metadata, or in the layer properties.

Is there a way to find out what raster magic I performed, or should I resign myself playing around with the raster calculator and eventually figure out what I did in the past?